# Use of check_box_tag, how get his value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I´m working to generate a PDF file with an option, this option makes visible a logo in the final PDF, I´m new in this and can´t hit the right answer

I made a plain check_box and then tried to catch a parameter, but this don´t work: <%= check_box_tag :logoless, "true", true %>

````
<a href="<%= pcf_generator_path(@legal_vacation, logoless: :logoless )%>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" 
            title="Comprobante de Feriado"class="btn btn-primary" role="button" aria-pressed="true" target= '_blank'>
            <%= "PCF" %></a>```

I want to be able to catch the value of a checkbox in url or in @legal_vacation variable (or directly if it´s possible).

http://localhost:3000/legal_vacations/pcf_generator/2?logoless=true <= like this
````

Comment: You are using a link, this will make a `get`-request, probably you should do it with a form instead, then your checkbox will be automatically submitted with the params.

Comment: Thank you for that suggerence, I decided to make it like a form at the end. I'll post my solution later, just for documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved using an attr_accessor called logoless.
Then I create a form with a check_box:

```
       <%= form_for(@legal_vacation, url: request_document_path(id: @legal_vacation.id),
          html: { method: "get" }) do |f|%>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-8 text-center">
              <%= f.submit 'PCF', class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
            </div>
            <div class="col text-center">
              <%= f.check_box :logoless %>
            </div>
           </div>
        <% end %>
```

And in my controller I take that value to assign it in my pdf's:

```
  def request_document
    @legal_vacation= LegalVacation.find(params[:id])
    vacation = LegalVacation.new(legal_vacation_params)
    @logo = vacation.logoless
    if params[:commit] == 'PCF'
      document_type = "pcf"    
    end
    pdf_info(document_type)
  end
```

And that all!